# How to work around: AmbiguousMatchException in Expression.Property(myNewExpression, "nameOfproperty")

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a class that looks something like this:

```cs
public class MyClass {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SomethingMore {get; set;}
}
```

I don't control the class. So I have to live with the fact that both `id` (lowercase i) and `Id` (uppercase I) exist. Like it or not, I cannot change this, hence this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42550850/4140832) answers my why, but it does not answer my how-to question.

In my Expression tree I have:

```cs
var newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes))

var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(newExpression, "Id");
```

The second line throws an `Ambiguous Match Exception`, because `Expression.Property(..)` is case insensitive - e.g. `Expression.Property(newExpression, "SomethingMore")` does **not** throw an exception.

What sort of work-around options do I have?

The next step in the code is:

```cs
Expression.Assign(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant("someNewValue", typeof(string));
```

I don't need to assign value to the `id` property and I know the meaning of `id`, which is special. I do however need to be able to assign a value to the `Id` property.

I guess I could create a derived version of my `MyClass`, that doesn't include the `id` property, but I need to do this at run-time. If this is the solution, how can it be done? Or, maybe there's a much better solution?

I don't control the `MyClass`. I only know that a developer would be inclined to define both `id`and `Id` in their class.

Comment: There are overloads for `Expression.Property`. Get the property info explicitly and use that.

Comment: I'm new to Expression Trees. Could you be more explicit? Example?

Comment: Ultimately, what are you actually trying to achieve with the expression?

Comment: I have a query expression that defines a query based on one or more primary keys for getting a document from Cosmos Db. The `id` property has a special meaning in Cosmos Db (i.e. it's the Resource Id) and it can be custom generated based on those primary keys. I'm trying to create an instance of MyClass with only those Primary keys that I know from the query, so that I can pass this instance to the generator to create the resource Id (`id`).  For more context see: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17310. Basically, I'm trying to improve EF Core for use with Cosmos Db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are overloads for `Expression.Property` that allow a more explicit means of accessing the desired property.

Get the property info explicitly using reflection and use that.

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);

var newExpression = Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));

PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("Id");

var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(newExpression, property);
```